# How to use the frame attribute for table in QTextDocument, even though it isn't supported?

Tags: c++, css, qt, html-table, qtextdocument

I'm trying to create a document using `QtTextdocument:: setHtml` function. The problem is according to the link below not all attributes are available for to me use from html.

> http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html

## Here is what I want to do

I have the following html which I want to print to a pdf using (QtTextdocument)

```html
<table width=100% frame='box'>
  <tr align='left'>
    <th>For</th>
    <th>Myself</th>
  </tr>
  <tr align='left'>
    <th>Attention</th>
    <th>Mother</th>
  </table>
```

The Html produces a table with a simple frame. The problem is the attribute "frame" is not within the supported Html Subset for Qt as indicated by the link [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html#block-attributes). The table tag is supported but not the attribute frame.

*Please note* that I had already tried using the attribute "border" and setting it to the value "1|0" but it gave borders around the table cells as well which is not what I want.

## Here is the C++ code to do it

```
QTextDocument *document;
QPrinter printer;
Qstring html="<table width=100% frame='box'><tr align='left'><th>For</th>"

        "<th>Myself</th>"+
      "</tr>"+
      "<tr align='left'>"+
        "<th>Attention</th>"+
        "<th>Mother</th>"+
      "</table>";
document->setHtml(html);
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
printer.setPaperSize(QPrinter::A4);
printer.setPageMargins(QMarginsF(15, 15, 15, 15));
printer.setOutputFileName("./Report.pdf");
document->print(&printer);
```

## My problem again

When I check the pdf, the table doesn't have the outside frame I want. Does anyone know a way around this? All I need is a black box around the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in the following manner. The idea is simply applying a black canvas under a white sheet.

I modified the html to be the following

```html
<table width=100% style='background-color:#000;'>
<tr>
<td style='padding:1px '>
<table width= 100% style='background-color:#fff;'>
  <tr align='left'>
    <th>For</th>
    <th>Myself</th>
  </tr>
  <tr align='left'>
    <th>Attention</th>
    <th>Mother</th>
  </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now I have a black border of 1px around the content and it is displayed very nicely on the pdf. ENJOY

Answer (score 2):

The `Frame` attribute of `Table` HTML tag is not supported by Qt.

Instead `Border` is supported. I tried with `Border`, I am able to see the border.

The below link has the list attributes supported for `Table` tag. Search for "Supported Tags" in below link.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html

You can see that for `Table` tag,

**Supports the following attributes: border, bgcolor (Qt color names or #RRGGBB), cellspacing, cellpadding, width (absolute or relative), and height.**

I tried below change in your code. I see borders.

```
<table width=100% border = \"2\" >
```

Comment: Thank for the answer but I only want the border around the table not the cells as well.

I indicated in the question that I already tried the "border" attribute and it was not giving the look I wanted.

I only want a border around the table not around each individual cell